# Problems with Spring Boot API (delete request)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What's up!?

I'm starting with Spring Boot API development with MongoDB. I'm taking a course about that and in the part of delete an user by id, I got stuck. See:

I have a controller named UserResource:

```
package com.victor.workshopmongo.resources;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import com.victor.workshopmongo.domain.User;
import com.victor.workshopmongo.dto.UserDTO;
import com.victor.workshopmongo.services.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> findAll() {
        List<User> list = service.findAll();
        List<UserDTO> listDto = list.stream().map(x -> new UserDTO(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(listDto);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> findById(@PathVariable String id) {
        User obj = service.findById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new UserDTO(obj));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@RequestBody UserDTO objDto) {
        User obj = service.fromDTO(objDto);
        obj = service.insert(obj);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(obj.getId()).encode()
                .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@RequestBody String id) {
        service.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

and a service layer named UserService:

```
package com.victor.workshopmongo.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.victor.workshopmongo.domain.User;
import com.victor.workshopmongo.dto.UserDTO;
import com.victor.workshopmongo.repository.UserRepository;
import com.victor.workshopmongo.services.exception.ObjectNotFoundException;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public User findById(String id) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = repo.findById(id);
        User user = optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Objeto não encontrado"));
        return user;
    }

    public User insert(User obj) {
        return repo.insert(obj);
    }

    public void delete(String id) {
        findById(id);
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }

    public User fromDTO(UserDTO objDto) {
        return new User(objDto.getId(), objDto.getName(), objDto.getEmail());
    }
}
```

When I send an delete request through Postman using any id, I get this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-26T21:18:54.465+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/users/64499188d3a8843737cc57dc"
}
```

Before you ask me if I'm inserting the correct id, there are the registered ids:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6449953dbd83981c4ca21358"
  },
  "name": "Maria Brown",
  "email": "maria@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6449953dbd83981c4ca21359"
  },
  "name": "Alex Green",
  "email": "alex@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6449953dbd83981c4ca2135a"
  },
  "name": "Bob Grey",
  "email": "bob@gmail.com"
}]
```

And this the request I'm trying do make with delete method:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/6449953dbd83981c4ca21358
```

If you need some more information, feel free to ask me.
I will leave here the github link too, if you need to see the full code: https://github.com/VictorHSM24/workshop-spring-boot-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@DeleteMapping("/{id}")`

and `(@RequestBody String id)` don't seem to match!

Please try:

`(@PathVariable String id)` instead.